# Lex - recognizing tokens

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am trying to learn Lex. I have a simple program where i want to read in a file and recognize tokens.

Right now i am getting some errors. I think i am having problems because there is more than one line in the file to recognize the tokens?

Here is the file

```
fd 3x00
bk
setc 100
int xy3 fd 10 rt 90
```

here is the output i am trying to achieve:

```
Keyword: fd
Illegal: 3x00
Keyword: bk
Keyword: setc
Number: 100
Keyword: int
```

here is my program:

```
%{

/* Comment  */

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

%}
%%
fd                     {printf("Keyword: fd\n");}
[0-9][a-z][0-9]        {printf("Illegal: 3x00\n");}
bk                     {printf("Keyword: bk\n");}
setc[0-9]              {printf("Keyword: setc\n Number: %s\n", yytext);}
int                    {printf("Keyword: int\n");}
xy3                    {printf("ID: xy3\n");}
fd[0-9]                {printf("Keyword: fd\n Number %s\n", yytext);}
rt[0-9]                {printf("Keyword: rt \n Number %s\n", yytext);}
%%

main( argc, argv)
int argc;
char** argv;
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {

        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(!file)
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s \n", argv[1]);
           exit(1);
        }

        yyin = file;

    }

    yylex();

}
```

here are the errors i am getting when i try to compile it:

```
 In function 'yylex':
miniStarLogo.l:11: error: expected expression before '[' token
miniStarLogo.l:11: error: 'a' undeclared (first use in this function)
miniStarLogo.l:11: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
miniStarLogo.l:11: error: for each function it appears in.)
miniStarLogo.l:11: error: expected ';' before '{' token
miniStarLogo.l:13: error: expected expression before '[' token
miniStarLogo.l:13: error: expected ';' before '{' token
```

is the error in my printf statements?
Thank you

Comment: That looks like a compiler error, are you having trouble compiling or running it? It compiles and runs for me, though the output isn't quite what you want.

Comment: thats the error i get when i try to compile it. I tried cc lex.yy.c -o myprog -ll

Comment: How were you able to compile and run it? What command did you use?

Comment: Does your lex file contain consistent line endings?  (e.g., all line endings are `\n` and not mixed with `\r` or `\r\n`)

Comment: @jeff - you can see the lex program above.

Comment: I just used `lex test.l; cc lex.yy.c -o test`. It appears Lex is misinterpreting your pattern somehow.  Check your line endings like Jeff said, if that doesn't work try adding white space (a blank line) above and below the `%%`.

Comment: If you are learning C (or Lex), learn very quickly to ignore non-prototype function definitions and declarations and only ever use prototype notation, so `int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compiled a copy of your code on MacOS X (10.7.2) with `flex` (2.5.35) and `gcc` (4.6.1), the only complaints I got from the C compiler were about the non-prototype definition of `main()`, and that was because I always compile with that warning enabled and mention of `yyunput() defined but not used` (which is not your fault).

Since you're learning C, you should only be using the notation:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
}
```

or an equivalent.

I also converted the `miniStarLogo.l` file to DOS format (CRLF line endings), and both `flex` and `gcc` seemed to be OK with the results - somewhat to my surprise.  It might not be the case on your machine.

When I ran the code on your test data, I got:

```
Keyword: fd
 Illegal: 3x00
0
Keyword: bk

setc 100
Keyword: int
 ID: xy3
 Keyword: fd
 10 rt 90
```

So, you are not far off where you need to be by my reckoning.

---

Confusion reigneth over my commands.

I used (hmmm, it was GCC 4.2.1 rather than 4.6.1), but:

```
$ flex miniStarLogo.l
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g -o lex.yy lex.yy.c -lfl
miniStarLogo.l:22: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
miniStarLogo.l: In function ‘main’:
miniStarLogo.l:42: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
miniStarLogo.l: At top level:
lex.yy.c:1114: warning: ‘yyunput’ defined but not used
$ ./lex.yy <<EOF
> fd 3x00
> bk
> setc 100
> int xy3 fd 10 rt 90
> EOF
Keyword: fd
 Illegal: 3x00
0
Keyword: bk

setc 100
Keyword: int
 ID: xy3
 Keyword: fd
 10 rt 90
$
```

(OK - I cheated marginally: the first time around, I ran `rmk lex.yy LDLIBS=-lfl`, where `rmk` is a variant of `make` and the compilation rules in the directory use the command line shown.  But I redid the compilations to get the error messages right, exactly as above.)

You might need to look at expanding your patterns to accept 'one or more' digits with `[0-9]+` in place of just `[0-9]`. You might need to look at a rule dealing with unmatched characters. And personally, I go to great pains to avoid blanks immediately before newlines, so you would need to tighten up your print formatting to meet my criteria. However, that's not germane to getting the program running.

Also, if you need to convert your file from DOS to Unix line endings, the easiest is the `dos2unix` command, if you have it on your machine.  Otherwise, use:

```
$ tr -d '\015' < miniStarLogo.l > x
$ od -c x
0000000   %   {  \r  \n  \r  \n   /   *       C   o   m   m   e   n   t
...
0001560  \n   }  \r  \n
0001564
$ mv x miniStarLogo.l
$
```

I carefully added the carriage returns using `vim` and `:set fileformat=dos`; it would also be possible to undo it with `vim` and `:set fileformat=unix`.  This is Unix so TMTOWTDI (There's More Than One Way To Do It -- the Perl motto), and I'm not even trying to use Perl.

Comment: I am using putty to log into a unix server. I also tried secure shell. Im not sure why this wont work on my machine.

Comment: Hey, i finally got it. i appreciate all your help. You were excellent. I did create the files on vim so i dont know why i was having problems. I did get it to run but i had to comment out the code where the print f was displaying the numbers. I also got the file to load. thank you